# For Polyaspartic garage floor coating, should I put down an epoxy vapor barrier?

Tags: garage, epoxy

The install will actually be done by a professional, but some use an epoxy primer instead of using all poly, some do the one day all polyaspartic package (which is all poly) and no epoxy at all.

(The epoxy is supposed to be way more moisture resistant for any issues with the cement, but the poly “stretches” with any cement swelling.)

We live in western NY and the house is six years old. Builder didn’t do plastic vapor barrier in garage before the cement.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Where are you planning to put the vapor barrier? Where is "western by"? You mention both "epoxy primer" and "polyaspartic package" - are we to assume that you're going with the later? If that's causing you an issue, are you sure the other option might not be better?

Comment: Added some clarification. I’m wondering which method we should go with. I don’t know if it’s common to have moisture issues with the all poly package.